# Is there a python unit test framework that gives compact error output when comparing strings

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using the Java JUnit framework and comparing the strings "abcde" and "abde" you would get the error output 'expected:<...b[c]d...> but was: <...b[]d...>'

Using python unittest I get "abcde" != "abde" which is not all as useful if you are dealing with long strings.

So my question is: Is there a python unit test framework that gives the same compact output as JUnit for Java?

Comment: If you don't find an answer you like, you could find some method of changing python unittest's output to match what you want (e.g., by running another program on its output).  Not sure what the best way to do this kind of think would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [unittest2 package](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/unittest2.shtml) is a backport (to Python >= 2.4) of features that are native to the PyUnit (unittest) framework in Python 2.7.

It includes enhanced string comparison features.
[image]
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/unittest2.shtml#unicode-string-comparison

Comment: What about long strings with just a single different word? Will it still print the entire string or only the part around the difference?

Comment: I believe it prints the relevant differences. Download it and see if it works for your use case. I think you'll find it useful. It's a drop-in replacement for the existing unittest framework you're complaining about.

Comment: Downloaded the python2.6 backport of unittest2. It does work, but it uses the assertMultilineEqual comparing unicode strings. And if there are now newlines in the string the output gets garbled. Oh well, at least it works. I also look at the code and found that it uses the standard difflib library, which I didn't know about. This means of course that I can use the library directly.

Comment: Cool. difflib is pretty handy, not sure how I forgot to mention that. Glad to be helpful.